# point to a custum setting in the template

Tags: css, django, sass

I want to create settings in the settings.py file that i can access in the templates that i use without passing the setting in ,in the views.py using django

```
settings.py
CSS_FOLDER_ROOT = "/home/brian/Projects/RaffleThis/RaffleGym/stylesheets"
```

CSS_FOLDER_URL =  SITE_DOMAIN + "/CSS/"

I want the server to serve the files from CSS_FOLDER_ROOT when HttpRequest is sent

working on the django template .html file and the views.py file

Answer (score 1):

I guess one way to do this is by creating a context processor.

Create a context_processors.py somewhere in your project

```
import settings    
def css_url(request):
    return {'CSS_URL': settings.CSS_URL}
```

Add the context processor in your settings

```
CSS_FOLDER_ROOT = "/home/brian/Projects/RaffleThis/RaffleGym/stylesheets/"
CSS_URL = '/css/'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
    "django_app.context_processors.css_url",
)
```

Then you can use something like this in your templates.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ CSS_URL }}<filename.css>" />
```

Comment: what will the server serve, it might only work because it's referencing my root dir. it neededs to come from SITE_URL /static/css

Comment: I updated the answer. You'll also need to configure the URLconf to serve the files from the CSS_FOLDER_ROOT

Comment: This seems like another question. Your question is answered - you have value from settings in template.